# How to tell which -ing verbs you can use as a noun?

Tags: verbs, word-usage

Example:

> I like Tom. He doesn't mind **my drinking, my nagging, my
>   dressing** - I can completely be myself around him.

I'm a little skeptical about this usage. Because even though I get [some](http://%22%20care%20about%20my%20dressing%22) hits on Google, I get [one or zero](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22%20care%20about%20my%20dressing%22&biw=1280&bih=938&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=IMJRVb_zJsz58QWX9YHQBA&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAQ) on Google Books. Plus, in other occasions, there's always something after the verb. Like ...[about my dressing habits](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=UcXuQZ5FrPYC&pg=PA227&dq=%22%20%20about%20my%20dressing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eMJRVe3_B8vj8AXzkoLIBQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA) and ...[about my dressing in female attire](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=KXCvy5uLUcQC&pg=PA184&dq=%22%20%20about%20my%20dressing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eMJRVe3_B8vj8AXzkoLIBQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **how I dress**

> He doesn't care about my drinking, nagging, swearing; **how** I dress, or cut my hair (etc...)

You don't say “my dressing” because in this case  *[dress](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dress)* is a  transitive verb, it requires an object.
Alternatively you could say: **my dressing *sense*** or ***style***. But I would opt for *clothes*

> He doesn't care about my drinking, nagging, or which clothes I wear—I can be completely myself around him.

Comment: Unless, of course, we're talking about food: _"He doesn't like my drinking, my nagging, or my dressing – he thinks I put too much celery in it."_ ;^)

Comment: @J.R. Oh gosh, do I *have* to include that as well?! :)

Comment: Sorry; I was just channeling my inner Groucho Marx.

Comment: Would *dressing* not be correct if he was talking about the act of getting dressed as opposed to the choices you make on how to dress yourself?

Comment: I agree with @Flater - it sounds the author is saying that Tom doesn't care that the author drinks, nags or wears clothes.

Comment: (Although I can't help but read it @J.R.'s way now it's been pointed out XD)

Comment: If it is transitivity that makes "dressing" impossible, why can we say "my drinking, my nagging, my dressing *in cowboy attire*"? or *...my dressing like  Spock*?

Comment: Dress is both transitive and intransitive. In the OP's example I understand that the speaker is talking about *how* they are dressed, their fashion sense or style. Of course there's nothing wrong in saying: "she's dressed **in** pink frills/ **in a** cowboy outfit / **as** Spock". But *dressing* used alone in that way sounds odd.